# Ignore zero values and continue with calculation in Python Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Is there a way I could continue with my calculation ignoring the Zero division error by ensuring Python returns a default zero for a Divide by Zero result.
Here is the block of code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Sales': [5000, 4000], 
    'COS': [0, 0], 
    'Inventory': [400, 500], 
    'Receivables': [150, 400], 
    'Days': [365, 366],}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Sales', 'COS', 'Inventory', 'Receivables', 'Days'])
df

sales = (data['Sales'][0])
cos = (data['COS'][0])
inv = (data['Inventory'][0])
recei = (data['Receivables'][0])
days = (data['Days'][0])

ans = (inv/(cos/days)) + (recei/(sales/days))
```

Apparently when I run it, it gives the ZeroDivisionError. Using the Try statement has not really given me a suitable solution. I would really love a solution that can be applied directly on the dataframe just incase other values too returns zero

**Ideally accounting-wise, my ans should be 10.95**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you'll find a straightforward in-line solution which automatically catches division by zero and return zero *for that term only*. Then proceed with the rest of the expression. You can define a function, use ternary statements or `numpy.where` with Pandas, but all these need explicit application.

Comment: You could also take a look at `numpy.true_divide` and `numpy.floor_divide`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### try / except

You can use `try` / `except`. You just need to include the inversion `1 / x` within the `try` part, and then multiply by the result instead of divide. One way is to define a function to do this for you:

```
def inv_div_try(num, denom):
    try:
        return denom / num
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0

ans = inv*inv_div_try(cos, days) + recei*inv_div_try(sales, days)

print(ans)

10.95
```

#### ternary statement

In one line, you can use ternary statements. This may be less readable:

```
ans = (inv*(days/cos if cos!=0 else 0)) + (recei*(days/sales if sales!=0 else 0))
```

Or wrap in a function as before:

```
def inv_div_try(num, denom):
    return denom / num if num != 0 else 0

ans = inv*inv_div_try(cos, days) + recei*inv_div_try(sales, days)
```

#### pandas

With Pandas, you can use `numpy.where` to vectorise your operations. Notice that with Pandas series, as with NumPy arrays, your denominator may have `0` elements but you won't meet `ZeroDivisionError`; instead, you see `np.inf` or `-np.inf`. In this case, we use `numpy.where` to avoid those results.

```
df['ans'] = df['Inventory'] * np.where(df['COS'] == 0, 0, df['Days'] / df['COS']) + \
            df['Receivables'] * np.where(df['Sales'] == 0, 0, df['Days'] / df['Sales'])

print(df)

   Sales  COS  Inventory  Receivables  Days    ans
0   5000    0        400          150   365  10.95
1   4000    0        500          400   366  36.60
```

Comment: Good answer. If I may, don't think `return denom / num` is intuitive for readers, Also, wouldn't it be better to `return d/n if n!=0 else 0` and avoid the wordy try/catch?

Comment: @RafaelC, Good point, I think I'll add that an alternative. I'm a bit more optimistic users will understand `1 / (n / d) == d / n` ! Personally I'm a big fan of `try` / `catch` (in general), if it quacks like a duck, etc.

Comment: makes sense ! I would do `div_try` returning `num/denom` as usual and just swap the arguments (or maybe let it as is and change func name to `inv_div_try`). But very thorough ans !

Comment: @jpp
Thank you so much guys. I adopted the second alternative by Rafaelc 
`def divis(n,d):
    if d != 0:
        return n/d
    else:
        return 0`
That way, I wont have to swap the calc, looks more tidy to me and understanding. Great job and thanks again.

Comment: @ZionOyemade, Great to here. Just to note, you should find the Pandas version performs best, in case it matters.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in this line:

```
ans = (inv/(cos/days)) + (recei/(sales/days))
```

`cos = 0` so `cos/days = 0` and then the code is trying to divide `inv` by 0